# How to count the number of instance of a custom class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance

I would like to count the number of instances of a custom class and its subclasses in Python3.x. How to do? Thank you very much.

I have tried the way class-member, but it doesn't work. The following are the codes

Base.py

```
class Base:

    ## class members
    __counter = int(0)
    @classmethod
    def _count(cls):
        cls.__counter += 1
        return cls.__counter

    def __init__(self):
        self.__id = self._count()

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.__id
```

SubBase1.py

```
from Base import Base

class SubBase1(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)
```

SubBase2.py

```
from Base import Base

class SubBase2(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)
```

main.py

```
from SubBase1 import SubBase1
from SubBase2 import SubBase2

s1 = SubBase1()
s2 = SubBase2()

print('s1-id', s1.id)
print('s2-id', s2.id)
```

The codes output:

```
s1-id 1
s2-id 1
```

But, what I want is:

```
s1-id 1
s2-id 2
```

What I should to do? Thank you very much at first!
PS: 
environment:  Ubuntu 14.04 + Python 3.4 + PyDev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the attribute on `cls` will set a *new* attribute on the subclasses. You'll have to explicitly set this on `Base` here:

```
class Base:
    __count = 0

    @classmethod
    def _count(cls):
        Base.__count += 1
        return Base.__count

    def __init__(self):
        self.__id = self._count()

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.__id
```

If you try and set the attribute on `cls` you create unique counters *per class*, not shared with all sub-classes.

Demo:

```
>>> class Base:
...     __count = 0
...     @classmethod
...     def _count(cls):
...         Base.__count += 1
...         return Base.__count
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.__id = self._count()
...     @property
...     def id(self):
...         return self.__id
... 
>>> class SubBase1(Base): pass
... 
>>> class SubBase2(Base): pass
... 
>>> SubBase1().id
1
>>> SubBase1().id
2
>>> SubBase2().id
3
>>> SubBase2().id
4
```

Comment: In my PyDev, it doesn't work well. But thank you very much. And, here I have to change the class method _count(cls) to _counter(cls) to make it works

Comment: @user365489: see my update with demo and further explanation. I've used Python 3.4 here too, I just haven't had my morning tea yet.

Comment: I have tried the your second code in my IDLE3. It works as follow:
>>> SubBase1().id
1
>>> SubBase1().id
2
>>> SubBase2().id
1
>>> SubBase2().id
2
>>>

Comment: @HAOXuguang: please do re-run the code I posted; you are setting the attribute on `cls`, not `Base`.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters: It works well now. Thank you very very much. By the way, what's the difference between cls and Base? I have set `@classmethod`

Comment: @HAOXuguang: the class method is bound to the *class of the current instance*; so `SubBase1` or `SubBase2`. `Base` directly references the base class instead.

Comment: That means, in the memory, classes `Base`, `SubBase1` and `SubBase2` are different ? If we want to access the member of class `Base`, we could only use the keyword `Base`?

Comment: Yes, they each are distinct objects. You are *setting* a new value for the counter. Experiment with `cls` versus `Base` and look at the classes with `dir()` to see what happens.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's very nice