# can python classes share variable with parent classe

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a class named `SocialPlatform` :

```
class SocialPlatform:
    nb_post = 0

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self._init_type()
        self.id_post = self._init_id_post()

    @classmethod
    def _init_id_post(cls):
        cls.nb_post += 1
        return cls.nb_post
```

and threee other classes that inherit from `SocialPlatform` :

```
class Facebook(SocialPlatform):
    _NAME = 'facebook'

    @classmethod
    def get_class_name(cls):
        return cls._NAME

    # code here


class Twitter(SocialPlatform):
    _NAME = 'twitter'

    @classmethod
    def get_class_name(cls):
        return cls._NAME

    # code here


class Instagram(SocialPlatform):
    _NAME = 'instagram'

    @classmethod
    def get_class_name(cls):
        return cls._NAME

    # code here
```

My idea was to increment `nb_post` each time an instance of `SocialPlatform` was created. I tought this variable was shared between all the classes that inherit from `SocialPlatform`

So I tested that in my main function :

```
def main():
    post = Post() # an other class with stuff in it, it doesn't matter here
    social_platform = {
        'facebook': Facebook,
        'twitter': Twitter,
        'instagram': Instagram
    }
    while True:
        try:
            platform = social_platform[post.actual_post['header']['platform']](post.actual_post['data'])
        except KeyError:
            print 'Platform (%s) not implemented yet' % post.actual_post['header']['platform']
            sys.exit(84)

        print 'platform name : ' + platform.get_class_name()
        print 'post id : ' + str(platform.id_post)
        # platform.aff_content()

        post.pop()
        if not len(post.post):
            break

        print 'enter return to display next post'
        while raw_input() != "": pass
```

but when I use this code I get this output :

```
platform name : twitter
post id : 1
enter return to display next post

platform name : facebook
post id : 1
enter return to display next post

platform name : twitter
post id : 2
```

With this method `nb_post` is shared between Twitter, Facebook or Instagram instance, not all of them.

So my question is : is there any way to do this in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an attribute is not found, it will be looked up on a higher level. When assigning, the most local level is used though.

For example:

```
class Foo:
    v = 1

a = Foo()
b = Foo()

print(a.v) # 1: v is not found in "a" instance, but found in "Foo" class
Foo.v = 2 # modifies Foo class's "v"
print(a.v) # 2: not found in "a" instance but found in class
a.v = 3 # creates an attribute on "a" instance, does not modify class "v"
print(Foo.v) # 2
print(b.v) # 2: not found in "b" instance but found in "Foo" class
```

Here `_init_id_post` was declared a `classmethod`, and you're doing `cls.nb_post = cls.nb_post + 1`.
In this expression, the second `cls.nb_post` occurence will refer to `SocialPlatform` the first time, then you assign on the `cls` object which is refering to the `Twitter` or `Instagram` class, not `SocialPlatform`.
When you call it again on the same class, the second `cls.nb_post` occurence will not refer to `SocialPlatform` since you created the attribute at the level of the `Twitter` class (for example).

The solution is not to use `cls` but use `SocialPlatform.nb_post += 1` (and make it a `@staticmethod`)

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly reference the base class in the increment expression:

```
def _init_id_post(cls):
    cls.nb_post += 1
    return cls.nb_post
```

Should be:

```
def _init_id_post(cls):
    SocialPlatform.nb_post += 1
    return SocialPlatform.nb_post
```

As per:

[How to count the number of instance of a custom class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590649/how-to-count-the-number-of-instance-of-a-custom-class)

Answer (score 1):

```
   class A():
       n = 0

       def __init__(self):
           A.n += 1



    class B(A):

        def __init__(self):
            super(B, self).__init__()


    class C(A):

        def __init__(self):
            super(C, self).__init__()


a  = A()
print(a.n) #prints 1
b = B()
print(a.n) #prints 2
c = C()
print(a.n) #prints 3
```

I think you can figure out the rest by yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
class SocialPlatform(object):
  nb_post = 0
  def __init__(self):
    self.id_post = A.nb_post
    A.increment()

  @classmethod
  def increment(cls):
    cls.nb_post += 1

class Facebook(SocialPlatform):
  pass

class Twitter(SocialPlatform):
  pass
```

And then:

```
>>> a = Facebook()
>>> b = Twitter()
>>> c = Twitter()
>>>
>>> a.id_post
0
>>> b.id_post
1
>>> c.id_post
2
```